# Datetime range custom filter not working

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to filter a list by time frame. I am using angularjs, bootstrap datetimepicker and moment.js. But what happens is I am not able to list the data. Without the custom filter I am able show the list and also do simple text filter search. I have added the code related to custom filter.

Code related to filter in Controller

```
 App.controller('ReportController', ['$scope', 'Report','$filter', function($scope, Report,
 $filter){
         var self = this;

         $filter('myfilter')(dateFrom ,dateTo);

         App.filter('myfilter', function() {
         return function(items, from, to) {
         var result = [];        
           for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
             var test = new Date(items[i].dateTime.$date);
             var month = test.getMonth()+1;
             var date = test.getDate();
             var year = test.getFullYear();
             var hour = test.getHours();
             var minute = test.getMinutes();
             var second = test.getSeconds();
             var newDate = year+"-"+month+"-"+date+""+hour+"-"+minute+"-"+second;          
             if (newDate > from && newDate < to)  {
                     result.push(items[i]);
                     }
               }            
             return result;
           };
           });
        }]);
```

In Html

```
<div ng-show="Sradioption == 'showSearch2'" class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'>
       <input type='text' ng-model="dateFrom" class="form-control" />
       <span class="input-group-addon">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
       </span>
</div>
<div ng-show="Sradioption == 'showSearch2'" class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
    <input type='text' ng-model="dateTo" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div> 

<table class="table table-hover">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>C_Number</th>
    <th>Datetime</th>
    <th>Reading</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr ng-repeat="r in ctrl.reports | filter:search | myfilter:dateFrom:dateTo">
    <td>{{r.c_Number}}</td>
    <td>{{r.dateTime}}</td>
    <td>{{r.reading}}</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you are using filter in both controller and ng-repeat.... I think one is enough.... what error you are getting in console?

Comment: I am getting Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: myfilterFilterProvider <- myfilterFilter

Comment: can you create a plunker

Comment: move filter code out of controller... try it... As @Sajeetharan said, create a plunker or fiddle it helps more...

Comment: @hemakumar if i move out, there is no error. but still list wont show. 
Ok i will try to create plunker.

Comment: try by removing $filter('myfilter')(dateFrom ,dateTo); in your controller

Comment: Yes removed that and tried.

Comment: check myfilter invoking or not by putting console logs and also i think your date comparison wont work perfectly .. Use momentformatdate.diff(momentformatdate2)

Comment: @Hemakumar its invoking myfilter. I could not create a plunker. I am new to this. Can you check on teamviewer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127987/discussion-between-hemakumar-and-user3844782).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take out the filter out of your controller,

```
App.filter('myfilter', function() {
    return function(items, from, to) {
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var test = new Date(items[i].dateTime.$date);
            var month = test.getMonth() + 1;
            var date = test.getDate();
            var year = test.getFullYear();
            var hour = test.getHours();
            var minute = test.getMinutes();
            var second = test.getSeconds();
            var newDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + date + "" + hour + "-" + minute + "-" + second;
            if (newDate > from && newDate < to) {
                result.push(items[i]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    };
});
```